# Unable to fetch the first option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am unable to get the `event.everyday` value though rest values are coming. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

**Scenario** -

1. Select `Every day` from the select option.
2. Click the "**click it**" button and check value in console.

**Problem** -

As `Every Day` was selected so I was expecting `forever` but its not coming let me know what I am doing wrong.

**Plunkr** -[PLNKR DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/wp7zRcX0pYOdMwkpj8Ze?p=preview)

Comment: Reason for closing ? I am really unable to locate what is wrong ?

Comment: When I paste my full code ..users say to merge it in a plnkr and now when I am providing plnkr they are expecting to write full code here..what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
<input type="radio" name="everyday" ng-model="event.everyday" value="forever" ng-value="forever" />
```

you have defined `value` and `ng-value`. If you left only `value` attribute it will work.

Comment: I know but if I drop `ng-value` then this radio is not default selected :(

Comment: @Trialcoder, you can set it by using ng-init `<div ng-if="event.repeat === 2" ng-init="event.everyday='forever'">`

Comment: tried this but no luck even this is breaking the default selection too http://plnkr.co/edit/S0jC6Wuyfq36rBuqmBEa?p=preview

Comment: @Trialcoder thats because you should remove `ng-value`, and use `ng-init`. http://plnkr.co/edit/JSQCnqOcR420uFrg4RUc?p=preview. In code you've posted above, there is still `ng-value` and that breaks the improvement.